# How can I know the list of all git branches containing specific commit hash

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I want to know all the branches that containing specific commit hash, is there a nice git or bash way to do so in one command [or one liner]?

```
--o--a--o--o--o   <-- master
         \
          b--o    <-- br2
           \
            c     <-- br1
```

For this example a exist in all three branches and b exists in br2 and br1.
I wish to find command like that:

```
find_commit <commit-hash>=b
output:
br2
br1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be done with

```
git branch --contains commit-hash
```

If you want to set a bash alias, you can do this:

```
alias blahblah='git branch --contains $1'
```

Then you could say:

```
blahblah commit-id
```

And if you like it and you want to keep it, you can set it in your profile file (that's a bash topic, not directly git related).

Comment: Do you have an idea how can I do it to all my repo, like in my example, want to write command and have a list of all branches with this commit hash

Comment: @OdedBD This is *precisely* what eftshift0's answer is doing :-) Did you try it yet?

Comment: now did, I was mistaken by the name branch [single] thanks :)